# how to overcome this "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(String?)'"

Tags: swift

I cant cast from string to double..received data from api is already a string

I tried `Double(lat)` but it didn't work

```
let lat  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLat
let Clientlat = Double(lat)
let long  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLong
let Clientlong = Double(long)
```

error is

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of
>   type '(String?)'

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+invoke+initializer+for+type+%27Double%27+with+an+argument+list+of+type+%27%28String%3F%29%27) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

`lat` and `long` are `String?` types, so you need to `unwrap` them before using,

```
if let lat  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLat {
    let Clientlat = Double(lat)
}
if let long  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLong {
    let Clientlong = Double(long)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first safely unwrap `clientLat` and `clientLong` due to it's String type with optional.

```
guard let lat  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLat else {
    return
}

guard let long  = clientLIst.data?[indexPath.row].clientLong else {
    return
}

let Clientlat = Double(lat)
let Clientlong = Double(long)
```